# How to measure the remaining bytes on std::fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream

This is how I open my `std::fstream`:

```
    f.open(filePath, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in |
                                 std::ios_base::out);
```

After calling some reads, how can I know how much bytes are left to be read?

I think `f.tellg()` (or tellp?) will tell the current position.

I tried doing some tests:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::fstream f;
    std::string filePath = "text.txt";
    f.open(filePath, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
    if (f.is_open()) {
    } else {
        std::cout << "ERROR, file not open";
        return 1;
    }
    //Write some data to vector
    std::vector<char> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    //Go to beggining of the file to write
    f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    f.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
    //Write the vector to file
    f.write(v.data(), v.size());
    f.flush();
    //Lets read so we see that things were written to the file
    f.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    f.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
    auto v2 = std::vector<char>(v.size());
    //Read only 3 bytes
    f.read(v2.data(), 3);
    std::cout << "now: " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "f.tellg(): " << f.tellg() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "f.tellp(): " << f.tellg() << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "end: " << std::endl;
    f.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    f.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
    f.close();
    return 0;
}
```

but my file won't open, I get an error. Also, I don't know how to measure the quantity of by

Comment: "*my file won't open, I get an error*" - Does `test.txt` exist? The combination of `binary | in | out` will fail if the file does not exist, see the table in the [`basic_filebuf::open()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) doc.

Comment: It's not easy to tell how much of a stream is left to be read. Typically a program is written to keep reading until if finds what it is looking for or there is nothing left.

Comment: Also, because a file stream implements internal buffering, so how many bytes are in the buffer doesn't necessarly reflect how many bytes are still unread in the underlying file. Your best option is to get the file size beforehand, and then keep track of how many bytes you have read from the stream so far, subtracting that value from the size when needed.

Comment: @user4581301 but how to get the filesize? I'm running on Android and std::filesystem is not ready. Wouldn't using tellg to get the entire size also suffer from the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've opened the file, you can `seekg` to the end with `f.seekg(0, f.end)`, then get current position with `tellg`. This will equal to the total number of bytes in a file.

Then, you `seekg` to beginning again, do some reads, and use `tellg` to get current position. Then, having current position and total file size is easy to calculate the number of bytes left in a file.